How can I make use of nextjs static generation in a Docker image shared between environments?
I'm building a nextjs app to be hosted in a Docker container. The content is backed by a headless CMS so content does change but not often. I therefore want to make use of static generation at build time then use next's cache revalidation rules to ensure the cached static pages are renewed on a schedule. So far, so good - this works fine.
For the record, this is accomplished by having a env.prod file containing environment variable definitions like CONTENT_API_ROOT=https://my.headless.cms/content which is copied by the Dockerfile COPY .env.prod .env.production then my fetch requests use URLs like process.env.CONTENT_API_ROOT + "/my-content".
This effectively binds the image to a specific environment.
The problem I'm facing is that when my PRs merge, our pipelines build a release candidate image which is deployed to a pre-production environment. Once approved, this same image is then deployed to production, thus ensuring our integrated test environments use precisely the same code as production.
But using the above approach means that I'm forced to configure this image to integrate with the production CMS when ideally I want it serving content from the test CMS in pre-prod and the prod CMS in prod. I hope I'm being clear enough.
If the answer is to revert to server-side rendering it's still not clear to me how I can inject a different API root URL at container runtime. Any advice much appreciated.
